# What are some methods for predicting a student's college course choice based on their course history?

Tags: classification, prediction, decision-theory

I'm working on a project where I attempt to predict what 8 (or fewer, ie. a student may take no course) courses a student will take in a given university year based on the courses they have taken in the past.

I've done some research to figure out a possible method, but am having trouble finding a method that easily handles a problem like this one. There are two major challenges that I'm having trouble wrapping my head around:

- The input (course history) is dependent both within a student's own history and between students, as all courses are capped at 20, meaning that some students choices will be constrained based on other student's choices.
- The target courses are different for each of the 8 outputs. In other words, there is a set of ~30 courses that differs for each of the 8 outputs I am trying to predict.

I'm not sure if I should be trying to break the problem down to use simpler methods or if there is a method that I can use to model the situation in full. I've considered Random Forests, which seem like a flexible method, but I wasn't sure how to deal with changing outputs. [This paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.05900v1.pdf) also describes a method that seems like it might be interesting / suitable, but it's a bit out of my depth. The choice of each output may influence the choice of other outputs as well.

Any advice or articles on working on this type of classification task would be appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like a recommendation system to me. The simplest way to do it is low-rank SVD approximation.